# Best container class for erasing a element

Tags: c++, containers, std, erase

I need to use the erase function but if I use vector, it would be very slow. What container should I use? I tried list but it didn't have random iterator access, which I need. Here's my code, a workaround would be fine too:

```
container <pair<ll,ll>> m;
for (auto i=0,j=1; j < m.size();)
{
    if (m[i].first > m[j].first)
    {
        cout << m[i].second << endl;
        m.erase(m.begin()+i);
    }
}
```

Edit: Using iterator and list works blazingly well.

Comment: In your example there is no need in random access iterators. Just don't iterate over indexes but over iterators.

Comment: Your example is very likely to run an infinite loop. It never increments either `i` or `j`. Since the code doesn't really make sense, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve with it, and therefore difficult to suggest a replacement.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180824133558/homepages.e3.net.nz/%7Edjm/cppcontainers.html  This gives the standard answer to your question. Look at the flow chart at the bottom. Or here: https://hackingcpp.com/cpp/cheat_sheets.html or here: https://github.com/gibsjose/cpp-cheat-sheet/blob/master/Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms.md

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. The reason I give this snippet is just for people to see what method I expect from the container

Comment: If you do want to use vectors, [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) should be a more efficient way. That is, use `remove` in your algorithm, then use the resulting iterator to `erase` the required elements in one go.

Comment: @sigma sure but I tried using list and it works super well